# How to get the 'predict_proba' for the class predicted by 'predict' in Random Forest Classifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

```
from sklearn import ensemble

model = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10)
model.fit(x,y)
predictions = model.predict(new)
```

I know [`predict()`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf3/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py#L608) uses [`predict_proba()`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf3/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py#L648) to get the predictions, by computing the mean of the predicted class probabilities of the trees in the forest.

I want to get the result of `predict_proba()` for the class predicted by  the `predict()` method.

What I'm doing is: first call `predict()` like in the above code, and for the probability I'm extracting the max probability from the trees like so:

```
all_probabilities = model.predict_proba()
class_probabilities = np.array([])
for tree in all_probabilities:
    class_probabilites = np.append(class_probabilities, tree.max())
```

Is this correct? If not, how can I extract the probability for the predicted class?

Comment: You sure want to do that? Because, from a modeling perspective, does not make much sense - when we get a probability value of, say, `0.7` in the binary case, we want to be certain that this means "*0.7 probability of being in class 1*"; with what you describe this will no more be the case, and a 0.7 could mean either "*0.7 probability of class 1*" or "*0.7 probability of class 0*", which, as said, does not make any sense.

Comment: @desertnaut in my case, there's around 1000 classes I want to predict. I want the probabilities in order to compare them with confidences of different models from different learning methods, and choose the prediction with the highest confidence.

Comment: Then, the answer below is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `predict_proba()` method returns a two-dimensional array, containing the estimated probabilities for each instance and each class:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

X = np.array([[1, 2, 3], 
              [4, 5, 6], 
              [7, 8, 9], 
              [10, 11, 12]])
y = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])

model = RandomForestClassifier()
model.fit(X, y)

model.predict_proba(X)
```

```py
array([[0.91, 0.09],
       [0.91, 0.09],
       [0.25, 0.75],
       [0.05, 0.95]])
```

As you note, for each instance the predicted class is the class with the maximum probability. So one simple way to get the estimated probabilities for the predicted classes is to use `np.max()`:

```py
np.max(model.predict_proba(X), axis=1)
```

```py
array([0.91, 0.91, 0.75, 0.95])
```